# get views customfield php value in another field

Tags: views

i create a views in drupal 6.24.set up some field like username and uid,
in third field used **customfield php** .with my custom php code filled this filed,
in another customfield php want use the value of customfield php value ,how can i do it?
i know with **$data->uid** (if userid exist im my views filed) can get current row uid.
i test $data->phpcode but return null to me. please tell me about how can i get customfield php in views?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way  to this is add your desire code in value section ,with return it, 
and in output section  use

```
<?php
 print $vlaue;
 ?>
```

with this method we can access all pervious variable in current and next php global field.
this descriptions are all about views_php module ;)

i hope this be useful for futures user with this problem,

Answer (score 0):

You should use the views_php module instead. It is the successor of Views Customfield PHP. The current module you are using does only render content, but has no value. views_php introduce the possibility to define both value and rendering settings. You should then be able to use the generated value in other fields.

Comment: with spend some hour search about this ,finally i use views_module but this module can provide my request, i want determine 5 field, 3 field are php, calucate some value in first and second and i third i want use pervious php field, i use ***$row->php*** ,and ***$row->php_1*** but return null to me !!!!